# Why does exec init work?

Tags: boot

After booting into /bin/bash to fix a problem, why does

```
init
```

or

```
/sbin/init
```

fail, while

```
exec init
```

runs `init` and boots.

Comment: I believe init is a bin file (a command list not an executable). exec is the executable command that runs a command list.

Comment: I imagine it's because the `init` daemon **must** be the parent of all processes; if run as `init` from the `/bin/bash` shell it would be a child of bash. By `exec`ing it, it takes over the original bash process's PID and becomes process 1

Comment: @steeldriver I guess you should post that as answer. The `man init` page also describes what happens when `init` (which equals `systemd` on modern systems) runs with PID 1 or anything else (running `telinit` instead).

Comment: @ravery Sorry, but no. Your comment is completely wrong here. And what you call a "command list" is named "script" or "shell script", which `init` is definitely not. And `exec` is also no script interpreter. Try reading `man init` and `help exec` to find out more about these commands.

Comment: @ByteCommander not sure I know enough to write a *good* answer - do you want to have a go?

Comment: @steeldriver Hmm... I don't really know any more than I already mentioned either. Please go ahead if you can.